# Is this a good enough reason for not taking an educational loan?

Tags: funding

I have recently been accepted for a degree program in Economics at LSE and am currently applying for Financial Aid. The application form expects that I have already applied for an educational loan to fund my education, but honestly, I have not. I intend to enter academia and so I think that in the near future (up until I do my Ph.D.) I won't be able to repay the loan. Will this be good enough for the committee evaluating my application?

Comment: "up until I do my Ph.D." Do you mean with this that you expect you won't be able to repay any loans until after you finished a phd, or until you start a phd?

Comment: until after I have finished a phd.

Comment: Do PhDs generally not have a salary attached where you live? And do education loans expect you to start repayment directly after finishing the degree, even if you are doing a PhD without a salary?

Comment: Usually, Ph.D.s do have a salary, but I guess that is just enough to take care of your living costs. The loans in my country require me to start paying up within a year's of notice and so supposing I do join a Ph.D. program, I will not be able to afford my living cost.

Comment: "I guess that is just enough to take care of your living costs" This is something to look into then. For example in the Netherlands a PhD student will get 2174 euros per month before tax in the first year increasing yearly to 2779 per month in the last year. This is by no means enough for a life in luxury, but with frugal living allows you to make considerable loan repayments. Also some loans have grace periods where you can stop repaying for a time, possible contingent on low income.  And of course essential here is the minimum repayment amount per month.

Comment: The thing is that I am not sure where would I get accepted as a Ph.D. candidate and so I cannot predict how much stipend I will be receiving in the future. It could be sufficient to repay the loans or it may not be. The student who has taken the loan is expected to repay after 6 months or 1 year after completion of the graduate program.

Comment: Then I'd ask the financial aid office. Explain to them that an educational loan would probably severely limit your options of persuing a PhD and that you rather not apply for one because of that. They must have seen this situation before (every year people apply for PhDs), so they could help you best knowing all your specific details.

Comment: I shall contact them right away. Thank you for your time and advice...

Comment: I'm confused.  Normally the reason to get a loan would be to pay the cost of being in the degree program (tuition, living expenses, etc).  If you don't get a loan, then you have to pay those costs yourself right away, instead of paying over time.  And if you don't have the money to repay the loan, how are you going to pay those costs?

Comment: I am applying for Financial Aid. The application form wants to know why I can't apply for loans. If I manage to convince them that I can't apply for loans, they'll give me enough scholarship to cover my costs.

Answer (score 1):

These are subtleties that could easily get your application dismissed on formal grounds. So the best thing you can do is talk to the appropriate department in the LSE directly. They may tell you it is ok, or they may point you to other options for taking educational loans. But they know (make) the rules, and we don't.